# A variadic C function for concatenating multiple strings

Tags: c, strings, variadic

I have this function that takes a number \$N\$, and \$N\$ C strings, concatenates and returns the result:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* mystrcat(int count, ...)
{
    char** p;
    char* result;
    char* ptr;

    size_t* len_array;
    va_list ap;
    int j;
    size_t total_length;

    if (count < 1)
    {
        return "";
    }

    va_start(ap, count);
    p = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);
    len_array = calloc(count, sizeof(size_t));
    total_length = 0;

    for (j = 0; j != count; ++j)
    {
        p[j] = va_arg(ap, char*);
        total_length += (len_array[j] = strlen(p[j]));
    }

    result = malloc(sizeof(char) * (total_length + 1));
    ptr = result;

    for (j = 0; j != count; ++j)
    {
        strcpy(ptr, p[j]);
        ptr += len_array[j];
    }

    *ptr = '\0';
    va_end(ap);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    puts(mystrcat(5, "Hello", ", ", "world", ", ", "friends!"));
}
```

As always, please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: Please note that there is nothing wrong with `p = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);`. Anyone saying otherwise are just mixing in subjective opinions in their review. Some prefer the `p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * count)` style (I do) but that's just personal opinions. The two styles are very similar and this is not a common cause for bugs, so it need to be mentioned in a general code review. Similarly subjective: it is good style to write `sizeof(char)` in malloc, so that your coding style remains consistent and that the code is self-documenting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Always return allocated string or never do it

This code here:

> ```
> if (count < 1)
> {
>     return "";
> }
> ```

is bad because you return a static string whereas the normal case returns a string allocated by `malloc`.  If the caller then tries to free this static string, it will cause some kind of error.  You can fix this by either returning an allocated empty string:

```
if (count < 1)
{
    return calloc(1, 1);
}
```

or by just returning NULL:

```
if (count < 1)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

#### Memory leaks

Your function never frees `p` or `len_array`.  Actually, I would probably not even use temporary arrays like these.  If I were to write this function, I would measure the total length on one pass, and then copy the strings on a second pass.

#### Rewrite

After fixing the above issues, my rewrite of your function would look like this:

```
char *mystrcat(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    size_t  len = 0;

    if (count < 1)
        return NULL;

    // First, measure the total length required.
    va_start(ap, count);
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        const char *s = va_arg(ap, char *);
        len += strlen(s);
    }
    va_end(ap);

    // Allocate return buffer.
    char *ret = malloc(len + 1);
    if (ret == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Concatenate all the strings into the return buffer.
    char *dst = ret;
    va_start(ap, count);
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        const char *src = va_arg(ap, char *);

        // This loop is a strcpy.
        while (*dst++ = *src++);
        dst--;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks for that.  I fixed up the rewrite.

Answer (score 5):

#### Automate consistency

> ```
>     p = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);
>     len_array = calloc(count, sizeof(size_t));
> ```

If you instead say

```
    p = malloc(count * sizeof *p);
    len_array = calloc(count, sizeof *len_array);
```

You can change the types of `p` and `len_array` without having to change these calls as well.

You should also check that these functions are successful.  Both return `NULL` on failure.

#### Prefer checking regions rather than points

> ```
>     for (j = 0; j != count; ++j)
> ```

If you write this as

```
    for (j = 0; j < count; ++j)
```

then it is more robust in the face of future changes.  For example, if you increment `j` an extra time in an iteration, the original might overshoot the mark.  This version will always stop.

C++ iterators have to compare against single values because of the way they work.  Working with a loop variable doesn't have that restriction.

#### Prefer `memcpy` over `strcpy`

> ```
>         strcpy(ptr, p[j]);
> ```

Since you already know the length and don't need to null terminate, you can use `memcpy`.

```
        memcpy(ptr, p[j], len_array[j]);
```

It might even be faster, as there may be a machine instruction for copying blocks of memory efficiently.  The `strcpy` command has to copy byte by byte, as the null could be anywhere.

#### Avoid memory leaks

It won't matter in a toy program like this, but you should `free` `p` and `len_array` before returning.  Otherwise each call to `mystrcat` would leak memory.

```
    free(p);
    free(len_array);
```

You should also do that in the caller.

> ```
>     puts(mystrcat(5, "Hello", ", ", "world", ", ", "friends!"));
> ```

Should be

```
    char *concatenated = mystrcat(5, "Hello", ", ", "world", ", ", "friends!");
    puts(concatenated);
    free(concatenated);
```

This won't matter in this program as it just ends and releases all the memory then anyway.  But in a longer running program that calls `mystrcat` many times, this could be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

- Avoid `sizeof(type)`. It disconnects type from the variable, and leads to double maintenance. Prefer

  ```
  p = malloc(sizeof(p[0]) * count);
  len_array = calloc(count, sizeof(len_array[0]));
  ```
- `len_array` leaks memory.
- `len_array` id strictly speaking unnecessary. Consider

  ```
  for (j = 0; i != count; ++j) {
      strcpy(ptr, p[j]);
      ptr += strlen(p[j]);
  }
  ```

  Of course it trades time (each `strlen` is evaluated twice) for space (no need for a `len_array`). I prefer this version because it avoids extra `calloc` (could be costly), and keeps the semantics of the increment clear.
- Surely you will get plenty recommendations to test the retrun value of `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out flaws in your code (although I'd add that sizeof(char) is 1 by definition), so I'll just offer an alternative strategy, namely to write a simple 2-string concatenation and use that if you need to join more strings:

```
char *mystrcat(const char * s, const char * t)
{
    size_t slen = s ? strlen(s) : 0;
    size_t tlen = t ? strlen(t) : 0;

    char *cat = malloc(slen + tlen + 1);
    if (cat) {
        memcpy(cat, s, slen);
        memcpy(cat + slen, t, tlen);
        cat[slen + tlen] = '\0';
    }
    return cat;
}
```

Three and four-string functions are simple extensions of this.