# Concatenate variable number of strings

Tags: c, strings

I am learning C on my own. This is not an assignment. I am trying to implement a function that takes a variable numbers of strings and concatenate them in a new string. It works, but I feel it is not elegant and would like to improve it.

For instance, I don't like how I am using n nor having to decrement argc twice, and I don't like having to use both `length` and `total_length`. On a more general level, I would like to know if there is a way to parse the variable arguments only once, although it does not seem to be possible unless allocating a fixed number of character or calling `malloc` multiple times (which I want to avoid).

```
/* 
 * concat_strings - concatenate a variable number of strings
 * usage:
 * const *message = concat_strings(4, "Error running", argv[0], " - ", "Action create: needs name and email");
 */
char *concat_strings(int argc, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    /* calculate the total number of characters in all the strings */
    va_start(ap, argc);
    int n = argc;
    int l = 0;
    while(n--)
        l += strlen(va_arg(ap, char*));
    va_end(ap);

    /* allocate memory */
    const size_t sizeof_char = sizeof(char);
    char *joined = malloc(sizeof_char * (l + 1));

    /* copy strings to destination */
    va_start(ap, argc);
    size_t length = 0;
    size_t total_length = 0;
    char *s;
    while(argc--) {
        s = va_arg(ap, char*);
        memcpy(joined + total_length, s, sizeof_char * (length = strlen(s)));
        total_length += length;
    }
    *(joined + total_length) = '\0';
    va_end(ap);

    return joined;
}
```

Comment: just found this one http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142638/a-variadic-c-function-for-concatenating-multiple-strings?rq=1
it looks like parsing arguments twice is needed

Answer (score 1):

Calling `strlen()` twice on each string is wasteful in time.

Current code make 3 trips down each string, once for length, once for copying, once to determine new length.

```
    l += strlen(va_arg(ap, char*));
    ...
    memcpy(joined + total_length, s, sizeof_char * (length = strlen(s)));
    total_length += length;
```

The following runs down each string twice, once for length determination and a second for copying.  It "parses" the variable arguments only once, but then does need to save those results somewhere.

```
char* concat_n(size_t n, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  size_t size = 1;

  // Allocate memory or for small `n`, use VLA or fixed array.
  struct {
    size_t len;
    const char *ptr;
  } str[n];

  va_start(ap, n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    str[i].ptr = va_arg(ap, const char *);
    str[i].len = strlen(str[i].ptr);
    if (str[i].len > SIZE_MAX - size) {  // Detect overflow in length
      va_end(ap);
      return NULL;
    }
    size += str[i].len;
  }
  va_end(ap);

  char *dest = malloc(size);
  if (dest) {
    char *p = dest;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      memcpy(p, str[i].ptr, str[i].len);
      p += str[i].len;
    }
    *p = '\0';
  }
  return dest;
}
```

---

An alternative to saving the lengths and recomputing `strlen()` is to use some non-standard function like `char *strpcpy()` which copies and returns the pointer to the null character.  As if this is faster than other approaches, YMMV.  IMO, `memcpy()` is the best to speed code along and since the length was  compute prior, take advantage of that even if managing the saving of those prior results is a minor extra burden.

---

`int` is not the best type for array index nor size math.  `size_t` is the [Goldilocks type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_principle), neither too wide, nor too narrow.

---

`sizeof_char` appears artificial.  Alternatives:

```
// char *joined = malloc(sizeof_char * (l + 1));
char *joined = malloc(l + 1);
// or
char *joined = malloc(sizeof *joined * (l + 1));
```

---

Defensive programming.  What happens if user passed a negative value for `argc`?   (Answer: a very long loop).

```
// Problem code when `argc < 0`
char *concat_strings(int argc, ...) {
  ...
  int n = argc;
  while(n--) {
```

Suggest either `size_t` or `> 0`

```
char *concat_strings(size_t argc, ...) {
  ...
  size_t n = argc;
  while(n--) {
```

or

```
char *concat_strings(int argc, ...) {
  ...
  int n = argc;
  while(n-- > 0) {
```

---

Check allocation

```
char *joined = malloc(l + 1);
if (joined == NULL) return NULL;
```

---

`argc`, though not a reserved name, has special meaning.  Suggest a different variable name like `string_count`